# How to build a proper decorator pattern or factory for Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, decorator

I am trying to build decorator pattern that it should get 2 parameters. First parameter is the function that should be decorated and second is the array of functions that should be applied to the main function.

For example:

```js
const decoratedFunc = decorate(shouldDecoratedFunc, [validate, confirmMessage("Are you sure")]
 
function shouldDecoratedFunc(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
```

The problem is that when I build the decorate function I just can't pass the parameters of the function that should be decorated to the decorate function. So I really don't know what to do. Or how to achieve this.

Can anyone help me who build something like this?

Comment: *I just can't pass the parameters of the function that should be decorated to the decorate function*: of course not, arguments are passed to the function **returned** by the decorate function. I'm other words, decorate should take functions as arguments and return a function.

Comment: Wiktor you should provide this as an answer, perhaps with an example. This is a classic example of people getting confused by passing a function vs calling one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do is below and it is actually works.

The problem with this one is when I want to execute the function that decorated conditionally, I just can't.

```js
function decorator(target, decorators) {
    const name = target.name
    const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, "prototype")
    return (...args) => {
        decorators.forEach(func => {
            if (func instanceof Function) func(target.bind(this, ...args) ,name, descriptor)
        })
        target.call(this, ...args)
    }
}
```

I'm open for any ideas